# Pygame Clearing The Screen

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a class and in the draw function, I draw a textarea, some static text, and color the screen. The draw function is in a while loop. I want the whole pygame screen to clear except for the input box and I want the screen to change color. How do I do that? My code is below:

`import pygame`

`from Settings import *`

`from TextInput import *`

`from Draw import *`

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

class Txt():

```
def __init__(self):

    self.running = True

    pygame.display.set_caption('TruTxt')

    self.input_box = InputBox(50, 550, 1200, 300)

def run(self):

    while self.running:

        self.events()

        self.draw()

def events(self):

    events = pygame.event.get()

    for event in events:

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

            self.running = False

        if event.type == pygame.K_RETURN:

            pass

        self.input_box.handle_event(event)

def draw(self):

    start()

    self.input_box.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

t = Txt()

while t.running:

```
t.run()
```

pygame.quit()

def start():

```
screen.fill((0, 0, 255))

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 64, True)
displaytxt = myfont.render(hellotxt , True, (255, 255, 255))
screen.blit(displaytxt, (300, 30))

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 24)
displaytxt = myfont.render(wlcmtxt , True, (255, 215, 0))        
screen.blit(displaytxt, (30, 200))

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 39, True)
displaytxt = myfont.render(strttxt , True, (255, 255, 255))        
screen.blit(displaytxt, (28, 370))

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 28, False, True)
displaytxt = myfont.render(destxt , True, (255, 215, 0))        
screen.blit(displaytxt, (165, 450))`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There seems to be something wrong with your post – not all of your code is marked as such, and the indentation seems off. Please [edit] and fix it – use the preview of your question to check if it's correct.

Comment: Please read the [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page.

Comment: why don't you just `screen.fill(newcolor)` and then draw the input box again. Pygame isn't really based on having "objects" its more about drawing to the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your summary at the top of your post i can conclude that what you need to do is simply redraw the screen at every iteration of the loop

```
screen.fill(color)
#redraw screen
```